# How can I convert from Vec<char> to u32 in Rust without going through String?

Tags: rust

My rust code runs in an environment where I have no access to `std::string` and `std::*` (but I have access to `core::str`). How can I convert a `Vec<char>` to `u32` without going through `String`, such as:

```rust
let num_in_chars: Vec<char> = vec!['1', '2'];

// some process here
// let num = ...
// This is how I could do it if I have access to `String`
// let num = num_in_chars.iter().collect::<String>().parse::<u32>().unwrap();
assert_eq!(12, num);
```

Thanks

Comment: If you have `Vec`, you do have `String` (that's basically the same thing).

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios but how would you do it without going through a String? 
I added some comment above on how I would do it if I can use String.

Comment: What I was saying is that AFAIK, there is no such an environment with `Vec`s but without `String`s.

Comment: It is a `no_std` environment, but my team import most of the `core` libs, and some of the alloc::*, so I have `alloc::vec` to use.

Thank you for your reply! 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must convert each `char` to a digit (in the `map`) and then you multiply each previous result by 10 and you add the new digit:

```
/// Returns `None` in case of invalid digit.
pub fn vec_to_int(digits: impl IntoIterator<Item = char>) -> Option<u32> {
    const RADIX: u32 = 10;

    digits
        .into_iter()
        .map(|c| c.to_digit(RADIX))
        .try_fold(0, |ans, i| i.map(|i| ans * RADIX + i))
}

#[test]
fn it_works() {
    let nums = vec!['1', '2'];
    let num = vec_to_int(nums);

    assert_eq!(Some(12), num);
}

#[test]
fn invalid_digit() {
    let nums = vec!['1', 'a'];
    let num = vec_to_int(nums);

    assert_eq!(None, num);
}
```